# How to download a KMS encrypted S3 object with a specific version id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am attempting to download a version of my object from my S3 bucket. What I have is KMS key id a.k.a --sse-kms-key-id bucket and file key as well as versionId. The command I am using is

`aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file_path/file.ext ./ --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:******:key/******-****-****-****-******** --profile my-profile`

But I am unable to find versionId support. Also if there is a way in s3api, that would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting specific version of file from S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599477/getting-specific-version-of-file-from-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 1):

The high level AWS CLI `s3 cp` command does not support object versioning.  You need to use the lower level `s3api get-object` command to specify a specific version.

Examples of command are given in this answer : [Getting specific version of file from S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599477/getting-specific-version-of-file-from-s3-bucket)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that files are encrypted and stored with server side encryption aws:kms. And I am not able to pass KMS encryption key id to lower level cli commands. Do you have idea about that?